# Rendering a React element to its initial HTML

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-dom, serverside-javascript

I'm trying to extract the initial HTML from react code on the server side. To do this, I'm using the official `react-dom/server` library function `renderToStaticMarkup()` referenced here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup

I'm reading a react source file, transpiling the JSX and ES6 syntax to CommonJS using Babel and then parsing the evaluated CommonJS to `renderToStaticMarkup()`.

### React code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return `<p>Hello World!</p>`;
    }
}

export default Test;
```

### Server-side code:

```
const { renderToStaticMarkup } = require( 'react-dom/server');
const Babel = require( '@babel/core' );
const Fsp = require( 'fs' ).promises;

(async () => {
    let fileContent = await Fsp.readFile( 'react.js', 'utf-8' );

    let code = Babel.transform( 
        fileContent, 
        { 
            presets: [ '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react' ],
            comments: false,
            minified: true
        }).code;

    let result = renderToStaticMarkup( eval( code ) );

    console.log( result );
})();
```

This example code returns an empty string `""` instead of the expected `<p>Hello World!</p>`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using the `React.createElement()` function on the evaluated component.

```js
    let result = renderToStaticMarkup( eval( code ) );
```

should be:

```js
    let result = renderToStaticMarkup( React.createElement( eval( code ), { props } ) );
```